# Ionic - Slides are "infinitely" sliding even if no more elements

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, infinite

I am making an Ionic App and I'm having problems when having 2 sliders in the page. Even if there are no more slides, it continues to slide making it impossible to go back to the last slide. I am living a video and code below.

Video:

[image]

Code:

```
<ion-row padding-left>
<ion-col style="padding-bottom: 0;">
    <ion-slides zoom="false" style="padding: 0; ">
        <ion-slide [class.oculto]="!oculto" *ngFor="let video of lista.videos">
           <button class="boton-slider" (click)="verVideo(video, lista.nombre)">
              <ion-thumbnail>
                 <img [src]="video.miniatura">
              </ion-thumbnail>
              <div *ngIf="video.visto" class="video-visto-lista">
                 <ion-chip color="primary">
                    <i class="icon-sm icon-ophthalmology" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="label-chip">Visto</span>
                 </ion-chip>
              </div>
               <p class="titulo-video">{{video.titulo}}</p>
            </button>
         </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
   <ion-slides style="height: 0;"></ion-slides>
</ion-col>
```

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hide the elements on the slide with "oculto" class. **You must use a filter pipe for filtering those slides**: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Do not use:

```
.oculto {
    display: none;
}
```

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterOculto'
})
export class FilterOcultoPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any): any {

        return items.filter(item => !item.oculto);

    }
}
```

So your code would be:

```
<ion-row padding-left>
<ion-col style="padding-bottom: 0;">
    <ion-slides zoom="false" style="padding: 0; ">
        <ion-slide [class.oculto]="!oculto" *ngFor="let video of lista.videos | filterOculto">
           <button class="boton-slider" (click)="verVideo(video, lista.nombre)">
              <ion-thumbnail>
                 <img [src]="video.miniatura">
              </ion-thumbnail>
              <div *ngIf="video.visto" class="video-visto-lista">
                 <ion-chip color="primary">
                    <i class="icon-sm icon-ophthalmology" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="label-chip">Visto</span>
                 </ion-chip>
              </div>
               <p class="titulo-video">{{video.titulo}}</p>
            </button>
         </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
   <ion-slides style="height: 0;"></ion-slides>
</ion-col>
```

Note that **you just need to add this to the *ngFor**:

```
  | filterOculto
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've just found the problem and it's because this component is a bit buggy if you use more than 1 in the same page. Did some workarround. I can't mark my answer as the solution tho until 2 days. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with 2 slide components in the same page and it worked with the pipe. Give it a chance. Good luck ;)

Comment: what have you put in the html to use the pipe and where? can you show that code part? full code would be even better

Comment: that doesn't work for me bec it only shows 1 slide at the same time and I need to show 1 and a half as the image in the first post show. And as I say in my own answer, if I use slidesPerView="1.5" it will do a nasty resize effect to the pictures

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it turns out that this was because I was resizing every slide to make the img smaller with the following:

```
ion-slide {
margin-right: 15px !important;
width: 65.3% !important;
}
```

But Ionic seems to calculate the maximum sliding with the `slidesPerView` and `spaceBetween` and as I didn't have them set in the HTML tag it was taking the default values which are 1 and 0 respectively.

So what I've done is to add these two propiertes to my HTML tag:

```
<ion-slides spaceBetween="15" slidesPerView="1.75" zoom="false" style="padding: 0; ">
```

and edited my styles for the slides to the following in order for it to fit properly to:

```
ion-slide {
margin-right: 15px !important;
width: 65.3% !important;
}
```

Incase you wonder why do I also edit the width and margin of the slides on the `scss` it's because before doing this I was using `spaceBetween` and `slidesPerView` but they were doing an awful effect where the images are big and then resize and move to fit what I set on those values because of these 2 little guys fault.

A bit dirty workarround for this buggy component.

Comment: You're save my life by decimal slidesPerView="1.75". Thanks!